# Returning an inner json string from Spring Boot RestController

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot RestController that is supposed to return a json (stored as-is in a DB column, and retrieved into a String object). I've broken it down to a few snippets

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
 ..... 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/restAPI/v2/get/mytest",...produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public RespBean fetchList(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,..) {
     ...
     String abc = userData.getJson(); //Json string
     System.out.print(abc); // gives {"name":"test", "desc": "My desc" }
     respBean.setData(abc)
     return respBean;
  }

}
```

And the RespBean is

```
public class RespBean {
    private String httpStatus, appCode;
    private Object data;
    //getters, setters ...
}
```

Now the trouble is, when I check the response in PostMan, I get a json escaped string for the data field, instead of a json 'object', like

```json
{
    "httpStatus": "200",
    "appCode": "21",
    "data": "{\"name\":\"test\", \"desc\": \"My desc\" }"
}
```

Can I tell the RestController not to escape the data field in the RespBean, and return it as a json object? Is there an alternate solution? I am trying not to change the structure of the RespBean (it is used in many places) and keep the status/code/data structure in as well.

Thank you for looking in.

Comment: Can you get plain userData instead of its `json` form?

Comment: The data is stored as json blob in the DB. To get it in non-json form I will have to create a new POJO and convert the json to that object, only for the framework to convert it back to json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonRawValue` for that

```
public class RespBean {
    private String httpStatus, appCode;
    @JsonRawValue
    private Object data;
    //getters, setters ...
}
```